# Use of ansprechen and besprechen in a construction

Tags: sentence-structure

Can we use both "ansprechen" and "besprechen" in this construction?

- Ich möchte zwei problematische Punkte ansprechen.
- Ich möchte zwei problematische Punkte besprechen.

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch, oder wurde auf dessen Gebrauch verzichtet? Was blieb danach unklar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, they just mean slightly different things.

ansprechen = to reference a topic

besprechen = to talk *with others* about a topic

You can raise/reference a topic without exchanging information about it - for instance if you're a politician giving a speech with no Q&A period.